# how can get data from facebook api and write those data in my own database using web services?

Tags: facebook, web-services, api

For this task I have already created my own facebook application to get the API key and secret key. Can anyone explain the next steps that should be done to

1) Read from facebook API 
2) Write my own database

by using **web services**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A high level answer:

I'm assuming you want to use the authorization code OAuth flow (this means you want Facebook users to give you access to their profiles so you can grab data from there). If so, you need to bring up a web server and an application that will run your users through the Facebook OAuth flow. In case you just want to access Facebook with your own credentials you don't have to have a web server, simply use the client credentials OAuth flow.

So, Once you have a valid access token, you simply make calls to Facebook API using this token. using Facebook Graph API is simply a matter of calling URLs and getting the data as JSON.

You can test-drive the API [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).

BTW, according to Facebook's [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/), you're only allowed to store Facebook data for caching purposes.

Let me know if this helps.